# How do I get around this error: E/FindingOpponentActivity﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated

Tags: android, parse-platform

I looked at the other solutions pertaining to this problem, and I have not found one that works in my particular case.

Overview: I am creating a turn-based multi-player app, two users are matched randomly, and then start the game.

Because the Parse query returns users who are available to play, I do not want users who are already matched to be included. However, I am unable to exclude both the matched users because of this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated.
```

This is a huge problem for me because of the following scenario:

Let's say User A wants to play the game, the field `READY_TO_PLAY` is set to true, and he is taken to `FindOpponentActivity` class. As there is no one else looking for a game yet, a toast appears telling the user this, and he is taken back to main activity.

Along comes User B, also looking for a game. He clicks on the Find random opponent button, and is similarly taken to `FindRandomOpponent` class. But wait! User A is also looking for a game! So user B matches with user A, and this code runs:

mCurrentUser.put(ParseConstants.KEY_READY_TO_PLAY, false);
mOpponent.put(ParseConstants.KEY_READY_TO_PLAY, false);

Now, this code works for the current user (User B) who will no longer be appearing in the list, but not for A.

Thus, if after a minute, user C appears, he is matched with A, so is D, E, and F. You get the idea.

How do I solve this problem?

```
public class FindingOpponentActivity extends Activity {

protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mOpponentRelation;
protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;
protected MenuItem mDoneItem;
public static final String TAG = FindingOpponentActivity.class.getSimpleName();
protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;
protected ParseUser mOpponent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_opponent);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar
    /*getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); */
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    mOpponentRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_OPPONENT_NAME);

    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_READY_TO_PLAY, true);
    query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT);
    query.setLimit(100);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            if (e == null) {
                //success!

                int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

                mUsers = users;
                mUsers.remove(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

                if (mUsers.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(FindingOpponentActivity.this,
                            R.string.no_player_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FindingOpponentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (mUsers.size() == 1) {
                    mOpponentRelation.add(mUsers.get(0));
                    mOpponent = mUsers.get(0);
                    mCurrentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    mCurrentUser.put(ParseConstants.KEY_READY_TO_PLAY, false);
                    mOpponent.put(ParseConstants.KEY_READY_TO_PLAY, false);


                    mCurrentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    mOpponent.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {

                            if (e != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Intent intent = new Intent(FindingOpponentActivity.this, StartGameActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```